# Python program does not execute beyond first user input

Tags: python, function

I have written a Python program that I expect to accept a "y" input from a user, and if the user inputs "y", do some simple calculations and print the results.

However it is not executing beyond
the user input even if that input is "y". Please help me locate the errors in the program.

The code is:

```
#This function is to get the user to input the data needed to use in the rest of the program
#It should return the 3 variables name, hrs_wrkd, and payrate

def get_info(name,hrs_wrkd,payrate):
    print('is this working?');
    name = input('What is the last name of the employee?');
    hrs_wrkd = float(input('How many hours did',name,' work last week?'));
    payrate = float(input('How much does',name,' get paid?'));
    return name,hrs_wrkd,payrate
#This function should be to calculate the employee's regular pay hours
#It accepts arguments from get_info

def calculate_reg_pay(hrs_wrkd,payrate):
    reg_hrs = hrs_wrkd
    reg_pay = reg_hrs * payrate
    OT_hrs = 0
    OT_pay = 0
    return reg_hrs,reg_pay,OT_hrs,OT_pay

#This function should calculate the Overtime pay for the employee
#It accepts arguments from the get_info function as well

def calculate_OT_pay(hrs_wrkd,payrate):
    reg_hrs = hrs_wkrd - 40
    reg_pay = reg_hrs * payrate
    OT_hrs = hrs_wrkd - reg_hrs
    OT_pay = OT_hrs * (payrate * 1.5)
    return reg_hrs,reg_pay,OT_hrs,OT_pay

#This function decides which calculation to use, either OT or regular pay
#It also accepts srguments from get_info

def calc_employee(hrs_wrkd,payrate):
    if hrs_wrkd <= 40:
        calculate_reg_pay(hrs_wrkd,payrate)
    else:
        calculate_OT_pay(hrswrkd,payrate)

#This function should print the single employee information after it was calculated
#It gets its arguments from the calc_employee function

def print_employee(reg_pay,OT_pay,name):
    print(name,'earned $',format(reg_pay,'.2f'),' worth of regular pay and ',format(OT_pay,'.2f'),' in overtime this week.')

#This function is supposed to calculate the running total of the hours and pay for overtime and regular pay for the company
# It accepts its arguments from the calc_employee function also

def running_total(reg_hrs,reg_pay,OT_hrs,OT_pay,total_reg_hrs,total_reg_pay,total_OT_hrs,total_OT_pay):
    total_reg_hrs = total_reg_hrs + reg_hrs
    total_reg_pay = total_reg_pay + reg_pay
    total_OT_hrs = total_OT_hrs + OT_hrs
    total_OT_pay = total_OT_pay + OT_pay
#This function is supposed to print out the running total for the company, but I realized that it isnt in the proper position when called

def print_totals(total_reg_hrs,total_reg_pay,total_OT_hrs,total_OT_pay):
    print('The total regular hours worked was',total_reg_hours)
    print('The total regular pay was $',format(total_reg_pay,'.2f'))
    print('The total overtime hours worked was',total_OT_hours)
    print('The total overtime pay was $',format(total_OT_pay,'.2f'))

# So here I am defining the main loop that will activate everytime the user selects Yes
#It calls most of the other functions

def main_loop():
    get_info
    calc_employee
    print_employee
    running_total
#Here I am defining the main program where I put the loop control


def main():
    loop_control = input("Would you like to enter an employee's name, payrate and hours? y to do so")
    if loop_control == "y":
        main_loop
    else:
        print_totals(total_reg_hrs,total_reg_pay,total_OT_hrs,total_OT_pay)
   #Here we call the main function

main()
```

Comment: hmmm this didnt post the way I would have liked.  Its for a class and Im just at a loss as to what Ive dont wrong

Comment: any tips on how to clean up the post will be appreciated also

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Try to state in the question what exactly the program is trying to achieve. Also; what language is this?

Comment: Put braces () on rhe main_loop call

Comment: You should edit the question to summarize what you expect to happen and what's going wrong. Including code is good, but you need to explain the context. The title should include a summary of what is expected, what's going wrong, and the language.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was SUPER Vague, but with only 150 chars, its kind of hard to describe all that's going on.  But generally the program executes but doesnt do anything.

Comment: The main loop executes, and prints the prompt for the user to enter y to continue but nothing else afterwards

Comment: @user3763612: That's no wonder, because you don't *call* any of your functions.

Comment: Calls to methods in python are done with brackets afterwards. This is your problem all throughout the code. for example, you call `main_loop` instead of `main_loop()`. Indeed, this will result in nothing being done, as it is correct syntax-wide. This is a very low quality question. I recommend a python tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *call* your functions. This does nothing but reference the function object:

```
main_loop
```

Add `()` to call a function:

```
main_loop()
```

Same in your `main_loop()` function:

```
def main_loop():
    get_info()
    calc_employee()
    print_employee()
    running_total()
```

Not that that'll work, because your functions take *parameters*; you need to pass those in in a function call to work. `get_info()` takes parameters it then ignores; remove those parameters in the function signature:

```
def get_info():
    print('is this working?');
    name = input('What is the last name of the employee?');
    hrs_wrkd = float(input('How many hours did',name,' work last week?'));
    payrate = float(input('How much does',name,' get paid?'));
    return name,hrs_wrkd,payrate
```

Next you want to *assign return values*; `get_info()` returns a few things, but you never assign any of them:

```
name, hours_worked, payrate = get_info()
```

Now you can pass these to *other* function calls:

```
calc_employee(hours_worked, payrate)
```

etc.

You'll have quit a few more to fix, that is outside the scope of this answer though. Don't forget to use `return` on function calls too! `calc_employee` doesn't return anything, for example, it simply ignores what the functions it delegates to return, for example.

Comment: well did that, now at least I am getting a traceback error :D, thanks

Comment: @user3763612: Then you are one step further on. There are many other errors in there, though.

Comment: Yeah, there are.  I KNOW the else statement kicks out, I have yet to figure out how to solve that but if I can get the rest running, maybe that will get me a bit closer.  We arent supposed to use any global variables

Comment: @user3763612: sure, and you are not doing that. But then you also need to make use of the function return values.

Comment: @user3763612: my advice? Start *smaller*. Write a program with just **one** function, make sure you know how to pass parameters to that and do something with the return value. Then expand from there. Here you are trying to do too much, writing the whole program from scratch. How will you know what changes make something work or break something now?

Comment: @Martijin Pieters-I understand what you are saying, and I guess Im gonna have to start over.  The function return stuff hurts my brain, Im used to just being able to define a global variable and move on... oh well

Comment: --Where do I put the assignation statement for the functions?